# restrict user access to sub domain if assigned to another sub domain

Tags: users

I have a site using the domain access module. I created 2 sub domains. agent1.example.com for agent1 and agent2.example.com for agent2. However, I can login to agent1.example.com with agent2 login info. I only want agent1 to login to agent1.example.com and agent2 to only be able to login to agent2.example.com.

The reason why I am using domain access instead of multi site is because I am sharing training videos, documents, and corporate documents across all sites. However, each agent will have their own page where they can track clients and sales statistics, so I want only them to see it.

What is the best way to go about this, or is there a better module for this? Or is there a way to share content across multi-site domains?

Thanks,
  cquigs

Answer (score 2):

the [Domain Bonus](http://drupal.org/project/domain_bonus) module can help you solve this problem.

> The Domain Bonus is group of modules that extend functionality of Domain Access module.

check the "Domain Bonus: Login restrict" sub module

Comment: I found this answer after finally stumbling on that module - but wanted to give it a +1. Shame i didn't find this some hours back ;-)